# Maven throws error while running testng test cases

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I have steup Eclipse + Maven + TestNG and I intend to run Selenium Test cases.

This is my POM File:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MyGroupId</groupId>
<artifactId>TestSuite</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.32.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Now when I try to run Maven test, I get following error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at 
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateOneArg(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireReflector.instantiateProvider(SurefireReflector.java:247)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.createProvider(ProviderFactory.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:171)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.surefire.providerapi.ProviderParameters.getRunOrderCalculator()Lorg/apache/maven/surefire/util/RunOrderCalculator;
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.<init>(TestNGProvider.java:67)
... 10 more

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Can someone suggest me what's that I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You have to define the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) in the pluginManagement section like the following:

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.14.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

To use testng in relationship with the maven-surefire-plugin you usually only need to add testng as a dependency nothing more.

Furthermore remove the dependency you've given:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Apart from the above this is looking more like an integration tests which is the job of [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) and **not** of maven-surefire-plugin.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
        <goal>verify</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This means your tests (presumably integration tests based on the selenium dependency) can be run by using:

```
mvn verify
```

Comment: I did the changes you suggested (added a plugins block in POM file and removed the surefire-testng dependency) but I still get an exception. Although this time I got a different exception.

Comment: Make a simple project which reproduce the problem and put the code with pom's etc. on Github.

Comment: I tried this solution, I still see the error after adding maven surefire plugin. I am also using maven + testng + selenium

Answer (score 3):

Maybe will help somebody.  Me helped - change version dependency of testng

It was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And has become:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had an issue that resulted in this error, but for me it turned out to be missing file access rights for the account running the tests to the test folder.

Might be something to check out

Answer (score 2):

changing the testNG dependency version in pom.xml from 6.14.3 to 6.10 will help out in avoiding the exception cases.

Comment: Hey Sandeep , the POM file shows version 6.8.1 is that the one that you are referring to change...

Comment: This is a perfect comment but not an answer. Read the rules, please.

Answer (score 0):

For me it got resolved after adding Surefire plugin in my Pom.XML as showed below:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and you have to make sure that, testNG.xml must be created.

You need to give the exact file name of testng xml file inside "suiteXmlFile" tag of pom.xml.

As per my understanding, this error was generated because of TestNG not configured with the maven Surefire properly, surefire are used to run our Tests. Since I'm using TestNg it must be configured with surefire.

Answer (score 0):

Attach following code in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```