# Selenium version 3.141.59 breaks existing testcases causes build failure

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to add add new UI integration test case in my project (using webdriver ). 
My Project initially has selenium ver 2.42.0. I tried to update version to 3.141.59 and observed maven test failures.

Error after running mvn install , test cases fail resulting in build failure:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@7a31ca20
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.symantec.epmp.scsem.web.management.controllers.SepUpgradeControllerTest
        at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:380)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:293)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:115)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:200)
        at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:153)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:536)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:159)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:113)
        at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
        at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:106)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

Here is my pom file test related dependency set up:

2.42.0

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>1.16</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.21</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdriver-selenium</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.7376</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-safari-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things that I can suspect is the dependency mismatch you have for selenium.

Remove all the selenium related dependencies except the `selenium-java` dependency. Others are redundant dependencies which may or may not interfere with the run. `selenium-java` includes all the submodules you need to run selenium tests.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

If you need to manage the driver server executables automatically (Ex: chromedriver.exe, gechodriver.exe), have a look at the https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager which works like a charm.

#### EDIT 1

The `timed out receiving message from renderer` issue seems to be an issue in chromedriver itself. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3332
Planned to be fixed in chromedriver v83.

However, there seems to be some workarounds for it.

1. Downgrade to chromedriver 79
2. Adding pageload strategy NONE in chrome options during creating the chromedriver

`ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);`

Comment: I removed the dependencies as you suggested and only kept selenium-java. Now i see below error msg:Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106  on port 21787
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[WARNING]: FromSockAddr failed on netmask[WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 81.
Apr 30, 2020 org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[1588217341.044][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100

Comment: From the error, it seems like you have the Chrome 81 version. and you are using the chromedriver v80. you have to use the correct chromedriver v81 to be compatible. Here is the link. https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.69/

Comment: I verified chrome version on my mac & it is 80. chrome driver is also ver 80. I read in another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300120 that this could be fixed by adding maven surefire plugin. i added the plugin, still the original error from the post persists.

`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <forkCount>3</forkCount>
     <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
     <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>`

Comment: Edited my answer with a possible solution